# Can a shared well system (2 houses) work independently of each other?

Tags: well-pump

I recently replaced the pressure tank (waterlogged) and pressure switch in my crawlspace that were part of a shared well with one neighbor. The plumber said that these components were the main tank and switch of the system and that my neighbor could not get water without the tank and switch on my property. My neighbor said that she had a pressure tank in her crawlspace and didn't need mine, so she was unwilling to share the cost. The plumber said hers was only an auxiliary tank that was used to maintain pressure for a longer period of time, but the system worked off of the components on my property. I'm trying to find out if it is possible that she is right and does not need my tank and switch for her to get water.

Comment: Anything is *possible*. The way to figure it out is to trace the pipes. Alternatively. Turn off your equipment for a day and see if the neighbor complains about the well not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your tank is a system necessity beside the pressure switch. Her tank might be nice to have, but it's not necessary for the system's operation.

The pressure switch and its pressure tank should be as close as possible. This prevents the pump from coming on every time somebody draws water or a leaky faucet drops 20 droplets of water (the exact thing that a pressure tank is intended to prevent). Having the two close to each other also reduces wear on the pressure switch due to pressure shocks in the system. A bad pressure switch imperils the pump, so it's wise to treat it with care.

Pressure travels in waves, where there's a lag between opening your faucet and the corresponding low pressure showing up at a pressure switch. The pressure tank acts as a hydraulic accumulator, where its trapped air expands to restore pressure after you've opened a faucet. I'm not sure if it's a quirk of fluid mechanics or maybe the pressure switch's inertia that prevents the pump from bumping on for a moment when the switch is close enough to the pressure tank. If they're even a few feet apart, though, the pump will come on with much higher frequency, where more cycles implies shorter pump life.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong question.   She does not "need" your tank just to get water.  She may benefit from it but that doesn't mean she has to pay for its maintenance. That is what you really want to know .... can you force or persuade her to pay?

Do you have access to deeds for both properties?   It's possible the sharing of the well is spelled out in them.  It isn't likely the deeds specify exactly who's responsible for technical enhancements but worth a look.  Without that, if she doesn't want to contribute I doubt you can force her.    Can you persuade her?  Probably not.  If each house has a pressure tank under it, and there is no written agreement, good luck persuading anyone that they work as a system and everyone is responsible for the maintenance of both, even if that's true.